# How to deal with WebServices error "any is not supported in sequence"?

Tags: java, data-acquisition, internet, webservices

I am trying to aquire data through Mathematica's WebServices and this example works just fine:

```
<<WebServices`
InstallService["http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx?WSDL"]
ConversionRate["USD","RUB"]
```

However, when I try to install this service:

```
InstallService["http://cbr.ru/secinfo/secinfo.asmx?WSDL"]
```

Mathematica returns with error messages:

```
LoadSchema::unsupported: any is not supported in sequence.
LoadSchema::elementschema: The element schema cannot be found for {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema, schema}.
```

I'm not very well versed in XML however it seems that there's an "any" tag present in the code of the service, is that a provider's mistake?

Comment: I once encountered this and then used Java instead to generate Web Service classes, then plugged into Mathematica. Of course this is of a little help, but the point is that Java version did work with the same service.

Comment: The funny thing is,  it was the same **exact** web service, which is `cbr.ru`.

Comment: Ok,since I have in the past looked at this exact web-service, I do have an already packaged Java - solution for it with a notebook illustrating the use of it from within Mathematica (in Russian). Send me an email on lshifr at  gmail if you are interested in this specific web service, and I could send you the files. I don't post this as an answer since this is a point solution for that particular web service.

Comment: @Leonid, I should confess that I'm the author of the original question which must have been forwarded to you (so I have the files). However I have absolutely no exprience with java so that I'm only able to use the solution you provided for that one service (Bank of Russia's site has many others) but not develop links for others. My ultimate goal is to develop a GetCBRData[] funtion and it would be nice to use the webservices as apposed to parsing the web pages. Anyway, thanks for your previuos answer!

Comment: I suspected that could be the case. Would love to help you with that, but I'm too busy with other stuff at the moment. One thing I could still suggest is to learn the very basics of Java and JLink, which may not be that hard actually. With those files you have, you won't need to actually *implement* any new Java functionality, just call Java methods from Mathematica. For that, you only have to understand how to create new Java objects via JLink and how to call Java methods on them via JLink, and may be M-Java core types conversion. This can be learned in a couple of days, really.

Comment: I will vote to close this question as too localized, since we have no evidence currently that this problem is encountered for any other web service. It might be that the web service in question is using something not fully supported by the standard, but that Java is just more permissive than Mathematica web services functionality. But we'll keep an eye on that, if that happens with more web services, we will perhaps reopen this again in the hope for a more general understanding and solution for this.

Comment: You can use http://rextester.com/runcode to run some simple complete Java examples interactively, to get a feel for it.

Comment: Ok, seems fair. Don't know wether it would be more productive for me to find a couple of examples of webservices using this "any" tag or actually look into jlink :)

Comment: Good question :). I was actually wrong, for other web services you will have to know how to generate Java classes for them, and probably how to use Eclipse and then package those services as jars. That is no big deal really, Eclipse has an automatic wizard to generate that, but will require a bit of extra time to learn. Don't know what is the best solution for you, that would depend on your programming background. But I still think that this is quite doable even for a complete Java newbie, given that in any case you don't have to write any Java code.

Comment: I did not remember how to do that by heart, so I used this [tutorial](http://px.pats.no/px/Eclipse_tutorial.html ) for those files I sent to you, and it worked with no problems.

Comment: "I will vote to close this question as too localized, since we have no evidence currently that this problem is encountered for any other web service". Well, I just encountered exactly the same problem with another webservice site, so I vote to reopen this question.